# Usage of overlay in web project?

Tags: java, maven, overlay, pom.xml

I have main webapp project which has dependency on web-generic. I see below configuration in my project. I have gone thru this link 
[overlay link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/mavens-war-overlay-what-are.....) which says overlays helps in avoiding code duplicacy. For example my wbapp1 and webapp2
bot want to have A.jsp. We can define the generic project with packaging as war. Then include the generic project as overlay in webapp1 and webapp2.
With this web resources of generic project will be included in main project. Is that correct?

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exploded</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>com.myComp.customer</groupId>
                        <artifactId>web-generic</artifactId>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myComp.customer</groupId>
        <artifactId>web-generic</artifactId>
        <version>${version.product}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Another question i tried commenting out overlay section and found same result i.e  jsp of generic project is still included under
webapp1

Comment: @ Q#1: yes, that's what overlays do. @ Q#2: did you run `mvn clean` inbetween? If not, that might be the reason, why you still have this JSP although you removed the overlay definition.

Comment: Yes i ran mvn clean . Infact i also tried manually deleting the target folder also. But still i found found jsp of generic project under webApp1

Comment: I just mentioned the war project as dependency. Still it is working as overlay configuration.